# Why this error?

Tags: warning-messages

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -0.5 <= x <= 0.5}}, 0];
ProbabilityDistribution[
 Integrate[f[a], {a, x - 0.5, x + 0.5}], {x, -2, 2}]
```

output:
"Unable to prove that integration limits {-(1/2)+x,1/2+x} are real. \
Adding assumptions may help. !(*ButtonBox[\">>\",
Appearance->{Automatic, None},
BaseStyle->\"Link\",
ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/Integrate\",
ButtonNote->\"Integrate::pwrl\"])"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) is an option to [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html). The message is telling you to add the assumption that `x` is real (by default, variables are usually treated as complex).

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -1/2 <= x <= 1/2}}, 0];
ProbabilityDistribution[
 Integrate[f[a], {a, x - 1/2, x + 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For this simple example one could also use

```
ProbabilityDistribution[
 Integrate[UnitBox[a], {a, x - 1/2, x + 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals], {x, -2, 2}]
```

or

```
TriangularDistribution[{-1, 1}]
```

(in case that helps).